# PHP JSON foreach trouble

Tags: php, json, foreach

I create a json structure with this php code:

```
<?php
    include "../base.php";

            $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers");
            $STH->execute();

            $result = $STH->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $rows = $STH->rowCount();

            $jsontext = "{";
            $jsontext .= "total: ".$rows.",";
            $jsontext .= "page: 0,";
            $jsontext .= "records: [";

            foreach($result as $key => $inner_arr) {
                $jsontext .= "{";
                foreach($inner_arr as $field_name => $field_value) {
                    $jsontext .= "{$field_name}: {$field_value}, ";
                }
                $jsontext .= "},";
            }

            $jsontext .= "]";
            $jsontext .= "}";
    echo json_encode($jsontext);
?>
```

the main problem is this line `$jsontext .= "{$field_name}: {$field_value}, ";`

When I print the whole script with "echo" it works. But with `$jsontext .=` it is not working and I receive only "**null**".

Comment: json_encode is a function to convert php arrays to json strings, you don't need to do any of those in foreach

Comment: simply use echo $jsontext;

Answer (score 0):

try using json_encode built in function

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

thank you to @Satya and @keune.

changing the last line from

```
echo json_encode($jsontext);
```

to

```
echo $jsontext;
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
            $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers");
            $STH->execute();

            $result = $STH->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $rows = $STH->rowCount();

            $jsontext['total'] = $rows;
            $jsontext['page'] = 0;

            foreach($result as $key => $inner_arr) {
                foreach($inner_arr as $field_name => $field_value) {
                    $jsontext['records'][][$field_name] = $field_value;
                }
            }
    echo json_encode($jsontext);
?>
```

p. s. i didnt tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
json_encode($jsontext);
```

with

```
echo $jsontext;
```